# How to have conditional dependency using 'dependsOnMethods' attribute?

Tags: selenium, testng

```
Class
{
    @Test
    public test1() {
    }

    @Test
    public test2() {
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test1", "test2"})
    public test3() {
    }
}
```

test3() should run after after test1() and test2().
But, it should be executed only if either test1() or test2() passes.

The current code would mean that, both the tests (test1() and test2()) should pass for test3() to run.

How can I use conditional (OR) dependency instead of depending on both (AND)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like OR condition is not there in TestNG. You can try alwaysRun=true even if depends method fails it will execute.

see https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods

Answer (score 1):

Logical AND and OR is not supported in dependsOnMethods attribute in Testng at the moment. You can refer https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1092. For now , you can manage your tests programmatically. something like this.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TryDependencyTest 
{
    boolean ans1, ans2 = true;

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        try
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
        catch(AssertionError e)
        {
            ans1 = false;
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void test2()
    {
        try
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
        catch(AssertionError e)
        {
            ans2 = false;
        }

    }
    @Test
    public void test3()
    {
        if (ans1 || ans2)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello , inside test3");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain two test classes calling the same test logic with individual depends on

```
@Test
public test1() {}

@Test
public test2() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test1"})
public test3() {
  if (!dependentTestExecuted) {
    callDependendentTestLogic()
    dependentTestExecuted = true;
  }

}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test2"})
public test4() {
  if (!dependentTestExecuted) {
    callDependendentTestLogic()
    dependentTestExecuted = true;
  }

}


private callDependendentTestLogic() {
  //your test logic
}
```